# Does dropping a battery on the floor partially discharge it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electricity, batteries

Can one mechanically discharge a battery? And if so, what is the mechanism responsible for that?

Comment: Why do you think this might be possible?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the battery structure remains intact, there is no reason why a battery should discharge when being dropped on the floor.